# Experience with Blitzer's "Algebra and Trigonometry" Book?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

Does anyone have any experience with it? Heard its super good but the latest 6th edition costs like 250, you can find the 4th for 30 bucks used. Know of any major differences?

Comment: Editions usually have minor section rewrites or new exercises. I suggest getting an affordable copy, or check your local used bookstore.